# How does CSS 3 border-image work exactly?

Tags: html, css

I have an image of 4x4 in size and I want to use it all around a DIV's border. The following:

```
-moz-border-image: url("../images/window/side.png") 4 4 4 4 / 4px 4px 4px 4px repeat repeat
```

will place left and right borders, but not bottom and top. What's wrong with it? I think I have misunderstood the syntax and if that is so, how does this syntax really work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the 4x4 image to be tiled along the border, you'll need to create a new image, 12x12 that looks like a square box with the border already tiled. Similar to this, where each diamond would be your 4x4 image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/images/border.png))</sub>

Then you'd just use this CSS:

```
border-image: url("border.png") 4 repeat;
```

The examples in the [official spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#border-images) may make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

did you try
`-moz-border-image: url("../images/window/side.png") 4 / 4px repeat;`
or
`-moz-border-image: url("../images/window/side.png") 4 repeat;`
with `border-width:4px;`
?